# .loc cannot find elements in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, search, row

I have a 6x2 dataframe called 'MyDataFrame'. Here is how it looks:

[MyDataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD1DE.jpg)

Its first column is called 'Keyword' and 2nd column is called 'Word'. I use the code below to find the row that contains a specific word in the 'Word' column.

Interestingly, the code works when I search for the word 'Aal' however it does not work for 'Aachenerin'

DOES NOT WORK

`List_of_Keywords = MyDataFrame.loc[MyDataFrame['Word'] == "Aachenerin"]`

WORKS

`List_of_Keywords = MyDataFrame.loc[MyDataFrame['Word'] == "Aal"]`

Any suggestions about why it is not working for 'Aachenerin'?

I also noticed something weird. When I copy the expression 'Aachenerin' from MyDataFrame and paste it into an Excel file, it pastes as 'Aa-che-ne-rin'. I have no idea where the dashes are coming from. Maybe the problem is about this.

Thank you so much for your responses in advance.

Comment: It's good that you noticed the `Aa-che-ne-rin` issue in Excel. There are probably some extra characters or formatting hidden in the string. You can try a site like this to find what's hidden inside. https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php You'll have to do some string cleanup before you can perform the match.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing that website. It looks like those dashes were soft hypens. I filtered them out and it worked!